# error occurred during mounting a folder in one server to another using putty?

Tags: directory, putty, mount

I'm using cloud. I want to mount a folder in the cloudstack management server to the system where xenserver is installed. But while doing it, error occurred. I have done so many things but error exist. I'm using putty.

```
[root@xenserver2 ~]# mount -t nfs 10.176.14.26:/mnt/secondary /secondarymount
mount: 10.176.14.26:/mnt/secondary failed, reason given by server: Permission denied
```

10.176.14.26 is the management server ip.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the folder is shared properly using [showmount](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/ubuntu-linux-nfs-client-configuration-to-mount-nfs-share.html)